# Java formatting

Tags: java, formatting

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter three positive integers seperated by spaces, then press enter:   ");
int a = scan.nextInt();
int b = scan.nextInt();
int c = scan.nextInt();
```

How do I make it so that when the users enter the numbers it shows up on the same line as the question and not below it?

Comment: Use `System.out.print` instead of `System.out.println`

Comment: You are so lucky!!!  [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) edited your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`

If you see the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.String%29) of `println()` it adds a new line after printing the data

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.out.print()` instead of `System.out.println()`.

Read the javadocs for each. `println(String)` "behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`", so you should just use `print(String)` if you don't want the new line.